# RelativeLayout: Many options if elements are GONE

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Isn't there a way to tell declaratively an element, position relative to many elements - if one is GONE then use the other? Of course if all elements are not GONE take only one (e.g. the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution is to use a LinearLayout inside of your RelativeLayout. So you can place elements inside the LinearLayout which then align to the previous element in the LinearLayout - either horizontally or vertically.

The framework itself does not support the feature to position an element relative to the visibility of many other elements.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see even remotely related to that is `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` and that says:

> If set to true, the parent will be used as the anchor when the
>   anchor cannot be be found for layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf,
>   etc. [boolean]

So I believe to get the functionality you want you would have to code it in yourself.

Comment: I know alignWithParentIfMissing, but it's not what I need.

Comment: I didn't think it was, but thought I would mention it just in case.  Good liuck!